# Line break at last file line ".txt" PL-SQL toad

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
Lv_Line:= Clave ||' '||ValorSeguridad; 
UTL_FILE.put(Lf_Archivo, Lv_Line);
```

The last Line makes me a line break and I need not to make the line break and the `UTL_FILE` library makes me the line break either with `Put` or `PutLine`.

I need the file to look like this:

[image]

Currently it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's expected; there's always an empty line at the end of file if you use text mode. But, if you use **byte mode**, then the line is *gone*.

This is something like you currently have, I presume:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_file utl_file.file_type;
  3    l_dir varchar2 (100) := 'EXT_DIR';
  4    l_filename varchar2 (100) := 'text.txt';
  5    l_line varchar2 (100);
  6  begin
  7    l_line := 'Test text';
  8    l_file := utl_file.fopen (l_dir, l_filename, 'W');
  9    utl_file.put(l_file, l_line);
 10    utl_file.fclose (l_file);
 11  exception
 12    when others then
 13      utl_file.fclose(l_file);
 14      raise;
 15  end;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> $type text.txt
Test text
                                   --> empty line here
SQL>
```

---

Do it this way (see comments which mark the difference):

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_file utl_file.file_type;
  3    l_dir varchar2 (100) := 'EXT_DIR';
  4    l_filename varchar2 (100) := 'text.txt';
  5    l_line varchar2 (100);
  6  begin
  7    l_line := 'Test text';
  8    l_file := utl_file.fopen (l_dir, l_filename, 'WB');           --> this
  9    utl_file.put_raw (l_file, utl_raw. cast_to_raw (l_line));     --> this
 10    utl_file.fclose (l_file);
 11  exception
 12    when others then
 13      utl_file.fclose(l_file);
 14      raise;
 15  end;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> $type text.txt
Test text
SQL>                               --> no more empty line
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH IT WORKED CORRECTLY.